# Android memory management calling Java class from native JNI and declaring data (for image conversion)

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, jnienv

I am writing native code for Android where I wish to uncompress a block of data.  I am calling a Java method from a native JNI function.  This Java method calls BitmapFactory and then tries to allocate some memory with:

```
int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
```

when the program seems to crash or stall or something, giving me **" spin on suspend "**, followed by much spew in logcat before the VM shuts down.

Just to give the big picture before diving into details, I'm trying to turn a byte array of a compressed image into a `width*height*bpp` uncompressed image to give back to native code.  I am trying to use the Android Java BitmapFactory to do the decompression which seems to work ok.  The compressed block of bytes is of a JPG or PNG image that was loaded into native code earlier (and not readable from disk in my system).

The sequence is a bit complicated, I'm not sure what's relevant so I'll say it all:
`class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer` method `onSurfaceCreated` calls native `init()` which is defined in the `MyRenderer`  class:

```
static {System.loadLibrary("glprog");
}
public native void init(int dummy_variable);
```

down inside native code this is the function called:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_pitransviewersingleimageres_MyRenderer_init(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj,  jint dummy_variable) {
glprog_init(dummy_variable);
}
```

which then calls another native function `char glprog_init(int dummy_variable)`which itself calls native
  wrapper_uncompress_image_by_os(overlay_compressed_data,overlay_compressed_data_len,...
here is the native function:

```
char wrapper_uncompress_image_by_os(unsigned char *compressed_data, int compressed_len,                     //input compressed data
                                char *data_name_string, char *suffix,                                   //name and type
                                int slot_num)  {
jstring jnamestring = (*preset_env)->NewStringUTF(preset_env,data_name_string);
jstring jsuffix = (*preset_env)->NewStringUTF(preset_env,suffix);
//create byte[] and copy data in
jbyteArray retArray = (*preset_env)->NewByteArray(preset_env, compressed_len);
if(retArray==NULL) {__android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "NATIVE","ERROR wrapper_uncompress_image_by_os: calling NewByteArray()");return-1;}
jbyte *javaptr = (*preset_env)->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(preset_env, (jarray)retArray, 0);
if(javaptr==NULL) {__android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "NATIVE","ERROR wrapper_uncompress_image_by_os: calling GetPrimitiveArrayCritical()");return-1;}
memcpy(javaptr,compressed_data,compressed_len); 
(*preset_env)->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(preset_env, retArray, javaptr, 0);

if((preset_javaobject!=NULL)&&(preset_method_id_convertimagefromnative!=NULL))
   {
   jthrowable exception;
   //call java function
   (*preset_env)->CallVoidMethod(preset_env,     preset_javaobject,preset_method_id_convertimagefromnative, 
                             retArray,compressed_len,
                             jnamestring,jsuffix,slot_num);
```

Which calls a method `convertImageFromNative()` in the same Java class `MyRenderer` that called native `init()`.

```
   public void convertImageFromNative(final byte[] data, int data_len, final String data_name_string, final String suffix, final int slot_num) {
    //writeFile(data,data_name_string);
    Bitmap bitmapqq=bytes2bitmap(data);
```

}

This appears to work so far, if I uncomment `writeFile()` it writes all the data ok to my SDcard.  It is inside `bytes2bitmap()` that I have problems.

The `bytes2bitmap()` class can be called from in 'regular' Java ok, but when called from this that is called from native it crashes at the `int[] pixels = new int[width * height];` line.

So finally here is the code that causes the crash:

```
Bitmap bytes2bitmap(byte[] bytes) {
    Log.d("startup", "Entered MyRenderer.bytes2bitmap()");
    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
    opt.inDither = true; 
    opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; 
    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, opt);
    if(bitmap==null) Log.d("running", "ERROR: GLESActivity.java: BitmapFactory() returns null");
    int width = bitmap.getWidth(); 
    int height = bitmap.getHeight(); 
    bytes=null;   //not sure if I should be freeing memory here, but it seems to work
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];    //crash happens here
    //crashes before doing the following
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height); 
    pixels=null;
    return bitmap;
}
```

I have not yet got to the part of passing the uncompressed data properly back down into native code, but thought I should address this first.

I could create an `int[]` array down in native code to pass up, the problem is that I don't know the uncompressed image size.

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem, it was a mistake in the code I didn't show.

The problem was in the `(*preset_env)->CallVoidMethod(preset_env,     preset_javaobject,preset_method_id_convertimagefromnative,` call in native code.  The variables preset_env,_javaobject,_method_id_, were set incorrectly.  I set them at the startup once to be re-used later using the native function _setupnative2java().  I have three classes in my project.  My mistake was in calling _setupnative2java() from my first Activity class, and not the MyRenderer class that actually contained the java method bytes2bitmap().  And during debugging I put another copy of this function in the first Activity class with the same name.  So it sort of worked but was had its pointers wrong.  It was strange in that modifications and logcat calls to the MyRenderer one would work.

I actually did call it from the MyRenderer class, but from with the startup Activity class with instancename.MyRenderer.setupnative2java.  But perhaps since it was called from this other class it didn't take the pointers for MyRenderer.  Plus I'm not sure how 'initialized' MyRenderer really was.  My apologies if you spent brainpower on this.

```
void Java_com_pitransviewersingleimageres_MyRenderer_setupnative2java(JNIEnv* env, jobject,javaThis, jint unused_variable) 
    {
    jthrowable exception;
    jclass class_id;
    preset_env=env;
    preset_javaobject=javaThis;
    class_id = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, javaThis);
    if(class_id!=NULL)
       {
       preset_method_id_convertimagefromnative = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, class_id, "convertImageFromNative", "([BILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V");  
       }
...
```